# Transfer selected objects to a collection doesn't work

Tags: collections

The <kbd>M</kbd> button does not work and does not allow me to transfer the selected objects to the collection

[image]

If several objects are selected via lasso or box and not one object at a time using the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key, the <kbd>M</kbd> button does not work and does not allow transferring the selected objects to the collection or create a collection.

Dragging and dropping from one collection to another works well on any tests with new files, but with my level of some problems. Maybe some objects have invalid connections or properties.

Comment: have you tried the same thing while being in object mode and not in edit mode ?

Comment: @Edmond there are object origins of multiple objects shown on the screenshot which are displayed in Object mode

Answer (score 1):

You can't transfer because there is no active object.

Pasting objects also lasso/border selecting doesn't set any object as active, and most operators in Blender use active object as reference for settings, since there isn't one some operations may fail.

Solve this by <kbd>Shift</kbd>-clicking any of the selected objects so it is set as active without deselecting others.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It was so easy to fix.